# Version control tool for postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Can anyone suggest a windows based version control tool for PostgreSQL.

Thanks and Regards,
GP

Comment: What's wrong with the popular choices like subversion or git?

Answer (score 23):

There are two tools which regularly get "honourable mentions" in this category. They are:

- http://www.liquibase.org/

and

- https://flywaydb.org

They are specifically for database version control - Open Source, Apache licence.

I believe that it's good to go to the source (pardon the pun...) in these matters. A Google of "database version control" leads one to [this post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/) by Jeff Atwood (one of the founders of StackExchange). Be **sure** to follow the links to [K. Scott Allen's](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/three-rules-for-database-work.aspx) series of articles. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-use-source-control-for-your-database-items) is an excellent thread which pretty much sums matters up (i.e. **version control** your database (or its metadata!)).

You could also look at [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) by [Martin Fowler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler) which is a thought provoking article on database version control and software development generally.

Comment: Liquibase is quite a good solution. We use it several projects.